# Google Actions integration with dialogflow different behavior from draft to alpha or beta

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

i created a chat bot with dialogflow (V1) and integrated it with google actions for Google Assistant. My company was supported by Google for all development process.

The first release of the chatbot was deployed for all users before 8 may. All works well and the actual release on Google assistant is working well.
The problem now is if i want update the bot with new actions and features the behavior of the chatbot is different in the simulator from draft state to aplha or beta release.

In the webhook the data provided by dialogflow is different (the logs on the cloud function): in the draft all parameters are set correctly , but when switch to alpha or beta version (created from the draft that works well) the parameters are always empty and all the bot answers are wrong.

There are specific actions to make or settings after 8 May to switch from draft to alpha/beta release of Actions on Google to avoid this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Alpha and Beta releases people made last August used to lack the training (machine learning) the agent received. It may be the case here that your alpha and beta versions have the same problem.

Comment: I'm in contact with google consultant. There is an issue on deploy process from draft to alpha, beta , release in google actions. They are working on to fix.

Comment: @Goodsoftw have you ever got this resolved? It looks like i'm experiencing the same thing now (V2 API)

Comment: @petrkotek , sorry for the delay , this issue has been fixed internally by developer team of dialogflow. Sometimes there are strange behaviors , like chatbot unhealthy error for 10 minutes. But this behavior has been fixed.

Comment: @r3vit any news for this issue. Our action is still broken for this problem.